# Fix SSMS connection dialog font size

Tags: ssms

I've installed SSMS on my desktop and for some reason it's rendering fonts in the Connect to Server dialog at some tiny size. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is it a 4K Monitor?

Comment: I'm connected remotely from a lenovo T470s.  1920x1080,166DPI display. I have fonts scaled to 125%.